# Why can't i get through this algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

```
// exmaple is passed
// strings = ["sun", "bed", "car"]  n = 1   //["car", "bed", "sun"]
// strings = ["abce", "abcd", "cdx"] n = 2 //["abcd", "abce", "cdx"]

function solution(strings, n) {
    let arr = [];
    let obj = {};
    /* before
    for(let i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        obj[strings[i].slice(n)] = strings[i]
    }
    */
    // after
    for(let i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        if (Object.keys(obj).includes(strings[i].slice(n))) {
            obj[strings[i].slice(n) + 1] = strings[i]
        } else obj[strings[i].slice(n)] = strings[i]

    let temp = Object.keys(obj).sort()
    let x = 0
    while(x < temp.length) {
        arr.push(obj[temp[x]])
        x++
    }
    return arr
```

To summarize the code

1. Receives an array of strings and stores the value sliced ​​from n as the key and the value as the strings value.
2. Sort by extracting the key value in the created object (even if there is the same nth character as in test case 2, the string after slice from the top is also received, so it is automatically sorted to the next value)
3. Sorted key values ​​are stored in an array in order by running a loop.

***I thought of the code in this way, but please give me some advice on where it went wrong.***

LINK  URL : https://programmers.co.kr/learn/courses/30/lessons/12915?language=javascript#

[image]

**> My result**
I don't know the parameters of the test case

[image]

Comment: Your solution seems to discard duplicate elements in the input array.

Comment: @FelixKling not only that but if you have `["aba", "cda", "xyz"]` with `n=2` then the first two elements are collapsed into one.

Comment: You could try to add the characters you sliced off to the end of the string like so: `obj[strings[i].slice(n) + strings[i].substring(0,n)] = strings[i]` even though that would still not resolve the problem with duplicate elements

Comment: Thanks for comments! I modified the code as advised
but not yet all passed...
`if (Object.keys(obj).includes(strings[i].slice(n))) {
            obj[strings[i].slice(n) + 1] = strings[i]
        } else obj[strings[i].slice(n)] = strings[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach will not work when the letter that becomes the `key` is not unique, you will overwrite that entry in your `obj` object, which will lead to an output that has fewer items than the input.

It will be easier to use the `sort` method directly, putting the logic in the callback function:

```js
function solution(strings, n) {
    return [...strings].sort((a, b) => (a[n]+a).localeCompare(b[n]+b));
}

console.log(solution(["sun", "bed", "car"], 1));
console.log(solution(["abce", "abcd", "cdx"], 2));
```

Comment: Thanks for comments! It's a way I never thought!
 I will study the localeCompare function!